# Multiple transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

hi below is the transactionManager which I've created in my spring configuration class.

```
@Bean(name = "dataSourceTXMgr")
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }



@Bean(name = "jpaTXMgr")
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    System.out.println("JPA");
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory.getObject());
}
```

But while calling the below method am getting an exception 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined

```
@Transactional(value = "jpaTXMgr")
    public Staff find(String userId, String password) {
        Staff staff = staffRepository.findOne(userId);
        return staff;
    }
```

@EnableTransactionManagement is already applied in my spring configuration class.  Please let me know what am missing

Comment: Could you post your complete configuration fir better understanding. Also , if you are using spring boot and spring data , then you don't need to define transaction manger as spring boot will do it for you. Another question , why do you need two tx managers?

Comment: You most probably shouldn't have two transaction managers. And you certainly should read the javadoc of EnableTransactionManagement, which precisely explains what it expects: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the 'EnableJpaRepositories' annotation, use it to set the transaction manager you want to use. See it's documentation for details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#transactionManagerRef--

What is happening is: While you specify your own transaction manager in your '@Transactional' annotation the repository comes with its own implicit annotation. So it is basically running inside of two transactions of which one fails.